# Загрузить XML файл из Assets

Tags: c#, unity3d

Мне нужно загрузить XML файл который лежит в Assets (к примеру lang.xml). 

Как это реализовать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Например, так:

```
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
TextAsset textAsset = (TextAsset)Resources.Load(filePath, typeof(TextAsset));
xmlDoc.LoadXml(textAsset.text);
```

Где `filePath` - путь к файлу.

Comment: Чет я не много туплю. Путь к фалу который лежит в папке с игрой или в папке Assets?

Comment: Например у вас есть файл: `Resources/Localization/ru-RU.xml`

Comment: Если вам нужно грузить с `dataPath`, то `string filePath= Application.dataPath + "/ru-RU.xml"; XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument(); xmlDoc.Load(filepath);`

Comment: Это работает. Только вот я использую не XmlDocument, а Xdocument.

Comment: Что Вам удобнее, то и используйте. LINQtoXML не помешает.

Comment: Только вот я продолжаю тупить. Я не понимаю как загрузить файл из ресурсов в Xdocument...

Comment: Используй `XDocument.Parse(текст)`

Comment: Упростил код использовав переменную textAsset что помогло убрать вторую строку твоего кода.

Comment: Можно и в 1 строчку записать, все как хотите